# Get the output color of RGBA over RGB

Tags: css, colors, less, opacity

I'm very new with LESS and still learning. How can I get the output color in RBG of a color with opacity over a base color?

For example:

90% WHITE over RED = #ffbfbf (pinkish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS has built-in [color functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations) to handle this.

In your case, you could get `90%` of white using [`darken(#fff, 10%)`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken). From there you could use the [`mix()` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-mix) to combine that with red at a specified weight.

For example:

```
background-color: mix(darken(#fff, .1), #f00, 75%);
```

Outputs:

```
background-color: #ffbfbf;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would that be possible to get the exact same result as my example above? It seems like the darken function output the 90% white as if it was on a black background, am I right?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Updated. You can run it through [this online LESS compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) if you want. It now outputs `#ffbfbf`, which is what you had.